# Lambda containing Method is not called from JSF

Tags: jsf, java-8, primefaces

I have a problem which occurs using Labda Expression and JSF 2.2

No matter which tag I use, as soon as the calling method contains a lamda expression, the method ist not called.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.doSomthing}" /> 

 public void doSomthing() {
      // never called
      // Lambda stuff happening
      List<Customer> charlesWithMoreThan100Points = customers
        .stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getPoints() > 100 && c.getName().startsWith("Charles"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

Without the Lambda Expression the Method is called as expected.

Debugging the actionListener has shown the `this.value.getValue(elContext)` does not trigger a call to the action method in the backing bean.

```
public void processAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws AbortProcessingException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
    StreamedContent content = (StreamedContent)this.value.getValue(elContext);
    // content is null. Value returning method is not called.
```

Comment: What server are you using? I remember we had issues with that in older Payara versions.

Comment: How do you determine that the method has not been called? It produces no result and no side effect.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, my dutch friend. I am using Glassfish 4.

Comment: Can you rewrite it as a non lambda?

Comment: Yes. It can be rewritten without using a lambda. But it woukld be a pity to do without lambdas.